# Scanning images for data using PHP

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, metadata

I am trying to sniff out image data using PHP. Basically I would like to scan an image and get some kind of hex, exif or data-uri from the image so it can be stored and compared. The purpose is not for any reason other than to compare and remove duplicates that are submitted.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: this might be useful to you: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html

Comment: phpocr is meant to recognize text in an image. The images I am trying to store/compare don't have text.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the md5 hash of  the image files to determine whether they are duplicate files.

```
 if( md5_file( $image1 ) == md5_file( $image2 ) ) { /* images are duplicate */ }
```

Comment: I've tested MD5 but it doesn't always produce the same hash. For example when I uploaded the same image to tinypic and imgur then downloaded it again the MD5 has changed.